# Parse case insensitive login

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse in my Xcode application and when I try to login with:

username: Admin 
password: test

it works. But when I enter

username: admin 
password: test

the login parameters are invalid. Is there a way to make Parse not case sensitive?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's up to you to implement it client side. Here are some examples: See [here](https://parse.com/questions/case-insensitive-username-and-email) I know you are coding in swift, but the topics of conversation should still make sense to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parameters Parse uses are case sensitive so it's up to you to implement the proper methods to rectify this *before* a user saves any User column properties. After the fact will be too late. So in short, let the user type whatever username they want and save it to the backend as a lowercase string. Then when they re-enter it, translate the user input string into another lowercase string and validate it against the backend (which is now a lower case representation)

Answer (score 3):

Basically what the link in the comment says is that when you create a new user object or before you let a user login call:

```
let username = usernameLabel.text
..........................
username = username.lowercaseString
..........................
//Then save the object
```

So it's not a way to make Parse case-insensitive but it eliminates the need to make it case-insensitive since everything is lowercased.

Comment: but that changes the username

Comment: @LucasChwe That's a problem if displaying the username (how the user styles it) is a key point of your app. If it is then you could either 1) Store the username how the user inputed it and filter with regex (might be an expensive operation) `query.whereKey("username", matchesRegex: "myUsername", modifiers: "I")` or 2) Use a separate column `displayUsername` for the user's direct input and use `username` for the lowercase version.

Comment: The latter would probably be better as Parse has specific methods for logging in.